# Inequality involving tangent function and constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, trigonometry

Under which conditions is this inequality correct?
$$
-8\cos(4\theta) C_1 + 16\sin(4\theta)C_2 > 0
$$
here $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants. Is this correct or am I missing something?

## Attempt

Rewrite as
$$
\sin(4\theta) C_2 > \frac{1}{2}\cos(4\theta) C_1
$$

##### Scenario: $C_2 > 0$ and $\cos(4\theta) > 0$

$$
\tan(4\theta) > \frac{C_1}{2C_2} \implies \theta > \frac{1}{4}\arctan\left(\frac{C_1}{2C_2}\right) + \frac{k}{4}\pi \qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

##### Scenario $C_2 > 0$ and $\cos(4\theta) < 0$

$$
\theta < \frac{1}{4}\arctan\left(\frac{C_1}{2C_2}\right) + \frac{k}{4}\pi \qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

##### Scenario $C_2 < 0$ and $\cos(4\theta) > 0$

$$
\theta < \frac{1}{4}\arctan\left(\frac{C_1}{2C_2}\right) + \frac{k}{4}\pi \qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

##### Scenario $C_2 < 0$ and $\cos(4\theta) < 0$

$$
\theta > \frac{1}{4}\arctan\left(\frac{C_1}{2C_2}\right) + \frac{k}{4}\pi \qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

##### Scenario $C_2 = 0$ or $\cos(4\theta) = 0$

No solution available